# Callback parameters mystery

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to understand a D3 portion of code coming from: 
https://github.com/square/crossfilter/tree/gh-pages (html file)

I'm wondering about what is the miracle behind the extracted and simplified code hereafter. My question is how parameters are passed to the render function.
`this` in my understanding corresponds to the chart object itself but from where is parameter `method` coming? What is the rule/logic behind? It seems to correspond to the `chart(div)` function.

```
var charts = [
   barChart()
      .dimension(hour)
      .group(hours)
      ...,
   barChart()
      .dimension(delay)
      .group(delays)
      ...,
   ...
   ]

var chart = d3.selectAll(".chart").data(charts)

function render(method) {d3.select(this).call(method);} 
function renderAll() {chart.each(render);}

function barChart() {
   ...
   function chart(div) { ...}
   chart.dimension = function(_) {...};
   chart.round     = function(_) {};
   ...
   return d3.rebind(chart, brush, "on");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**selection.each(function)**

> Invokes the specified function for each element in the current selection, passing in the current datum d and index i, with the this context of the current DOM element.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#each

Comment: Thanks David for your answer, I understand the 'this" parameter quite well now, but the major point for me is still understanding the method parameter that seems to be a barchart object sub-function (chart(div))... I don't understand how it is selected and sent to the render function